# Rename [pu-battlegrounds] -> [playerunknowns-battlegrounds]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I would like to propose renaming the tag for PlayerUnknown's Battlegrounds.

- [pu-battlegrounds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pu-battlegrounds) -> [playerunknowns-battlegrounds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playerunknowns-battlegrounds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Done:**

- [pu-battlegrounds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pu-battlegrounds), [pubg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pubg) -> [playerunknowns-battlegrounds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playerunknowns-battlegrounds)

Answer (score 2):

I agree, given that the current name was established because of old character limits on tag names.